# django url with parameter

Tags: python, django

I want a django url to look like this:

```
event/1?type=fun
```

so far I have:

```
url(r'^events/(?P<event_id>[\w\-]+)/(?P<event_code>[\w\-]+)/$', views.web_event)
```

which would be:

```
 events/1/fun
```

what is the technique for changing it to parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are confused of `GET` parameter with django url parameters. The parameter after `?` is an http request `QueryString` that exists way before django does. You cannot control that with django url definition.

[Django doc about GET and POST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#get-and-post).

[Wiki about query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

**Edit**:

As I stated above, it's a `GET` parameter not a `POST` parameter, so if you want to use it in your views, you should fetch it from `request.GET`:

```
var = request.GET.get('q')
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. You are already changed it into a parameter called `event_code` in your url definition, what else are you looking for?

Comment: if my link is localhost/url/?q=3, in django would I use request.POST.get('q') to return 3?